# Appropriate use of Very Low Quality flag

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

Every now and then, I'll get a flag declined for some reason or another, but this one has me a little bit perplexed.

When we are doing First Post Reviews, from time-to-time we'll hit an audit to make sure we're playing attention.  When passed, it mentions what some of the other actions would have been appropriate.  In this example, it specifically mentions that *flagging as Very Low Quality* was the correct thing to do.

[image: First Post Audit]

However, I came across this post earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648544/parallel-block-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/33664080#33664080.  The post content is simply:

> After all solved it with loop activity. It is so simple)

This doesn't even begin to explain the answer, and is quite useless in my opinion for anyone that might stumble upon the same issue.

But the flag was instead declined with:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

What gives here?  I don't understand how this doesn't fit into the *Very Low Quality* bucket (it's hardly even an answer, should it be flagged as *Not An Answer* instead?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes these flags warrant a discussion about dealing with content and how to approach various aspects of those patterns. However, I don't think this scenario needs any of that.

The answer was a comment at best, and did not attempt to answer the question nor include a solution or anything relevant to solving the problem.

I think the community will action it appropriately, and hope that the moderator who declined your flag simply made a mistake here.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that moderators only see the answer when they handle your flag and they hopefully know nothing about SharePoint.

With that *a loop activity* might be just enough to get people solve the issue raised in the question. Deleting the answer would possibly mean that the moderator will destroy useful content which is better left at the community. Hence they declined your flag.

A better cause of action is to down vote the answer and/or leave a comment (as @Deduplicator just did for you).

Use the VLQ flag for things that are not understandable/utter crap/gibberish/not in English. Don't use flags to indicate wrong content, use down votes for that.

Comment: Understandable - but one thing that still has me confused is why it's suggested that flagging as VLQ is the correct action in the review audits.

Comment: That review was a link only, probably even spam answer. The answer you flagged didn't have those properties.

Comment: If it's spam, it should be flagged as spam, not as VLQ.

Comment: I said *probably* so I'm good @JoshCaswell

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't disagreeing, just emphasizing the importance of identifying spam correctly for the spam-repelling system.