# Low quality post flag declined

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

During Low quality posts review queue, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340971/home-shortcut-not-created-on-cyanogen-os) question. This question didn't contain what asker tried to solve his problem, nor what problem he faced while attempting to solve his problem neither any steps to reproduce the problem(If any). Based on the above said assumptions, I **flagged** this post as  **Low Quality**.
But my flag was declined with the following reason:-

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support

So, are my assumption wrong for this Low Quality posts or moderator got it wrong?

Answer (score 4):

This question should be downvoted and closed, and OP should be notified (by a comment) about the reason for the downvote, in order to help them improve future posts.

There are many VTC-reasons that can fit "lack of research efforts" posts, you can pick one of them, but I don't think the question should be deleted.

Comment: so according to you this is not Low Quality Post?

Comment: @Vivek _Low quality_ is SO jargon.  If something is bad (the literal meaning of low quality), downvote.

Comment: @VivekMishra It is, but I wouldn't flag it. There are other actions you can do, like downvoting and VTC.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had the same situation but with discussion with community manager here I found that VLQ should used when you cannot interpret content out of the post.

If you have problem with post that the op didn't tried to solve out the problem and straight away asked the question you can downvote and comment.

And regarding the post you mention op's question lacks details but it's title and the post he link is somewhat self explanatory. So IMO it is not VLQ warrant to be deletion.

see here also.

[Appropriate use of Very Low Quality flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310086/appropriate-use-of-very-low-quality-flag)

Comment: According to `Congratulations` box text from the answer that you have linked, flagging low quality is also an appropriate actions